# Prefer certain nodes until full

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I've got an AKS cluster configured with two fairly small VM worker nodes, and then a virtual node to use ACI. What I really want to happen is for pods to get scheduled on the two VM nodes until they are full, then use the virtual node, but I cannot get this to work.

I've tried using node affinity, as suggested [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/virtual-node-autoscale/virtual-node-autoscale-demo/), but this just doesn't work, pods get scheduled on the virtual node first. If I use a required node affinity, then they do get scheduled only on the VM nodes, but that is not what I want. I am guessing the issue here is that the resource availability on my VM nodes is significantly lower than the virtual node (as you would expect) so the virtual node is getting much more weight applied to it, which counteracts the affinity rule, but I don't really know as I can't see any way to see this weight.

So, does anyone have a way to make this scenario work?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.

Comment: @jww I'm well aware of the different network sites, however the Kubernetes Github specifically directs people to raise questions in Stack Overflow, not Serverfault.

Comment: Kubernetes does not decide what is on-topic at Stack Overflow. That is already decided and detailed at the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If you provide their GitHub, then I'll raise a bug report with them and provide them links to the Help Center. (This is not the first time a company tried to offload support onto Stack Overflow).

Comment: Ok, how about the fact that Kubernetes has 21,000 questions on Stackoverflow, and 850 on Serverfault? This is a question about developing applications that run on Kubernetes, it is not an infrastructure question, it is a question about how to work with Kubernetes

Answer (score 1):

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling/kube-scheduler/ goes over the different scoring options used by the scheduler and https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/blob/master/staging/scheduler-policy/scheduler-policy-config.json shows how to customize them.

I suspect what you want is a `preferred` affinity combined with increasing the scoring factor for `NodeAffinityPriority`.

Answer (score 0):

`nodeAffinity` is the right way to go, but you have to play right with `requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution` and `preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution` parameters.

For example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: node-affinity
spec:
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: KEY-FOR-ALL-THREE-NODES
            operator: In
            values:
            - VALUE-FOR-ALL-THREE-NODES
      preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - weight: 100
        preference:
          matchExpressions:
          - key: KEY-FOR-THE-TWO-SMALL-NODES
            operator: In
            values:
            - VALE-FOR-THE-TWO-SMALL-NODES
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
```

This pod can run only on the nodes with the `key: value` stated as requirement (so all three nodes), but you are giving it a preference to run on the small nodes (if there is room), with weight of 100. The weight is a subjective thing, so it should work the same with +1 then with +100.

Also, since you have three nodes, you can skip requirement part, and only set a preference.

Comment: I don’t have any requirement affinity, solely a preferred one. Unfortunate it seems this is ignored, or other weights are impacting it.

Comment: are you positive you still have room for the new pods? k8s will give 100m core of resource request by default, if nothing specified. You have this space?

Comment: Yeah, if I switch this to a require policy it will load up the vNet node with about 8 of these pods before it runs out of resources.

Comment: weird. Could be AKS thing? I just made a test on GKE and worked as expected. I don't have different node pools though.

Comment: I’m wondering if it is related to resources. The vm node is a 2 core 8gb box, whereas the virtual node shows up with 800 ores and 4TB, is the difference causing it to weight in favour of the virtual node because it has so much more resource free.